# URLs don't work within production - return 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

This issue seems to be well documented but all solutions people suggest on posts don't work for me :/

I managed to fix urls giving 404 on my localhost by applying

--history-api-fallback

to the "scripts" package.json

however when I move the production over to my apache2 setup, any url I manually type or refresh returns 404, on site navigation works fine.

for example, http://www.craftmc.net/ works but http://www.craftmc.net/login returns 404, despite that url working if i navigate to it on site.

I saw a post saying use this .htaccess,

https://hastebin.com/alifavacil.apache

Sadly it didn't work. :/

navigation in question - https://hastebin.com/xevecefoda.xml

Comment: Try this

https://medium.com/@kayode.adechinan/host-react-application-on-apache-server-90c803241483

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure Apache to serve your app on all URLs that it's supposed to handle.

By default, Apache will only serve your app when the user requests the specific path where the app is located, say for example www.example.com

If you now try to visit www.example.com/user/123, Apache will try to find a file named "123.html" inside the "user" folder. You have to tell Apache that what it should do is reply with your app even if the path requested by the browser doesn't actually point to your app within the filesystem on the server.

You can do this in several ways, but a common one is to use mod_rewrite. For example, you might try something along these lines:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com"
AliasMatch "^/myapp" "/opt/myapp-1.2.3"
<Directory "/opt/myapp-1.2.3">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase "/myapp/"
    RewriteRule "^index\.html$"  "welcome.html"
</Directory>
```

For more information about mod_rewrite and the various directives it uses, refer to [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), and/or google.